# database mail in SQL server 2014 express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I have an issue with my sql server 2014 express edition , I need to configure database mail, and I already follow some steps like the steps on the below link :

http://tanmayas.blogspot.nl/2008/11/configure-mssql-database-mail.html

but the main issue with me is that I can not see the database mail on management section as you can see :

[image]

any suggestion on how to show it ?

thanks and best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the list of supported features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx) Database Mail is not available for the Express edition.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx) link

> Database Mail is not available in SQL Server Express.

So alternatively what you can do is refer [**this**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/02/sending-mail-using-sql-server-express-edition/) article.

Well you can also use sql clr to send mail. Refer [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1795/send-email-from-sql-server-express-using-a-clr-stored-procedure/) article.

Comment: why can you please elaborate @krishna

Comment: @mohan111: Don't know exactly but just think - sql express edition comes with limited features. So database mail feature dependent DMVs or some other functionality on which it depends may be not available in express edition. I think that's the reason its not available in any express edition.